# How to setup multiple for loops together?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested

I am trying to understand the placement of the `for` loops to have them in the proper order. I am unsure of where to put the j loop in this code. The goal of that loop is to have the velocity u change over time using 
 `u=2*sin(2*pi*T)`. This u is placed in the upwind 1D advection equation, which is then plotted to show what happens over time. As of right now, with the current setup, the plot is stationary at the initial position. Could anyone provide some helpful tips on how the `for` loops need to be sequenced? Thank you.

```
clear;
clc;
%Set initial values
xmin=0; 
xmax=1;
N=101; %Amount of segments
dt= 0.0001; % Time step
t=0; % t initial
tmax=2; % Run this test until t=2
T=t:dt:tmax
u=2*sin(2*pi*T); %Velocity

dx = (xmax - xmin)/100; %finding delta x from the given information
x =xmin-dx : dx : xmax+dx; %setting the x values that will be plugged in

h0= exp(-(x- 0.5).^2/0.01); %Initial gaussian profile for t=0
h = h0;
hp1=h0;
nsteps =tmax/dt; % total number of steps taken
for n=1 : nsteps
    h(1)=h(end-2); %Periodic B.C
    h(end)=h(2);

        for i =2 : N+1 
            for j=1:nsteps
                if u>0            
                hp1(i) = h(i) - 2*sin(2*pi*T(j))*dt/dx *( h(i)-h(i-1)); %Loop to solve the FOU 
            elseif u<0            
                hp1(i) = h(i) - 2*sin(2*pi*T(j))*dt/dx*(h(i+1)-h(i)); %downwind
                end
            end
        end

    t=t+dt; %Increase t after each iteration
    h= hp1; %have the new hp1 equal to h for the next step
    initial= exp(-(x- 0.5).^2/0.01); % The initial plot when t =0
    %hold on

    %plot(x,initial,'*') %plot initial vs moving
    plot(x,h,'o-')
    pause(0.001);
    %hold off


    %plot(x,initial) %plot end value
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in the postion to assess if you have implemented the algorithm in the right way, so I can not say if the sequence of `for loops` and the computations you make inside them is right, nevetheless there is a mistake in the way you've defined the `if` section.

Consider that the variable `u` is actually an array.

In your `if` section:

```
 if u>0
    hp1(i) = h(i) - 2*sin(2*pi*T(j))*dt/dx *( h(i)-h(i-1)); %Loop to solve the FOU
 elseif u<0
    hp1(i) = h(i) - 2*sin(2*pi*T(j))*dt/dx*(h(i+1)-h(i)); %downwind
 end
```

you test the whole array so the result, being `u` an array, is an array of `logical` (0 1) values (one for each element of the array `u`); this makes the `if` not able to catch the condition you look for.

You should modify the `if` section in order that just one element of `u` is tested at each iteration notice the **if u(j)>0** isntead of **if u>0** (same for the `else`):

```
 if u(j)>0
    hp1(i) = h(i) - 2*sin(2*pi*T(j))*dt/dx *( h(i)-h(i-1)); %Loop to solve the FOU
 elseif u(j)<0
    hp1(i) = h(i) - 2*sin(2*pi*T(j))*dt/dx*(h(i+1)-h(i)); %downwind
 end
```

now, at each ieteration the `j-th` value of the array `u` is tested.

Again, I'm not in the position to judge if the algorithm is correct, so I can not say if this simple modification will solve the problem.

The following is the figure I've got after the first iteration of the outer loop having modified the `if` condition as described above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @il_raffa for catching that! I originally had the u value as a constant 1 or -1. This makes sense as the u changes with respect to the value or j!